# Crm Dynamics 2011 on Windows Server 2012 - Installing

Tags: windows, installation, crm

I'm following a link by Daniel Craig on installing -http://danielcai.blogspot.ca/2012/05/install-crm-2011-on-windows-server-8.html

Getting Windows Server 2012 running has been like getting hair out of wool. Not quite so stable yet. I miss my Linux already but need Crm.

Could anyone assist me with the files from Windows Server 2008 R2

```
Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.dll
rmConfigHelper.dll
ServerManagerCmd.exe
svrmgrnc.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd not be installing it on Server 2012. It's clearly not a supported platform (Without UR13), so why would you do that?

Comment: Agreed. Server 2008 R2 is the preferred, and supported, platform for CRM 2011 at this time.